# Is there a list of built-in functions in python2 that were removed in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

python-2.x has a list of [non-essential built in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#non-essential-built-in-funcs) but python-3.x has no such list, and clearly there are [built in functions in python-2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) that are no longer in [python-3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).  Is there a list somewhere of all the python-2.x built in functions that were removed in python-3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The list of removed built-ins in 3.0 can be found here.](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)

There are a few functions that were renamed:

- `intern()` was moved to `sys.intern()`.
- `raw_input()` was renamed to just `input()`. The old behaviour can be emulated by using `eval(input())`.
- `reduce()` was moved to `functools.reduce()`.
- `reload()` was moved to `imp.reload()` in 3.0, and subsequently moved to `importlib.reload` in 3.4.
- `xrange()` was renamed to `range()`, replacing the old `range()` builtin.

And one function resurrected:

- `callable()`, which was removed in 3.0 and resurrected in 3.2.

Comment: Couple omissions from "renamed" list: `reduce` -> `functools.reduce`, and a multistep rename, `reload` -> `imp.reload` (3.0+, deprecated in 3.4) -> `importlib.reload` (3.4+). Few people used the former, but the latter is commonly used in interactive sessions during development, I usually tweak my `PYTHONSTARTUP` file (executed only for interactive sessions) to automatically do `from importlib import reload` so I can use it without explicitly importing or qualifying it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Added!

Comment: `xrange()` to `range()` is another significant one.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @JohnColeman Also added - that is one function I never seem to remember...

Comment: Note: Py3's `range` is better than Py2's `xrange`. For one, from the start, it had no value or size limits; `xrange` couldn't produce values outside the range of a C `ssize_t`, and couldn't have a total number of items greater than `SSIZE_MAX`. Py3.0 `range` has no such limits (though you can't take the `len` if it exceeds `SSIZE_MAX`), and in later 3.x releases they made other improvements, like `O(1)` membership testing and logical equality testing, support for slicing, etc.